# Django & Couchdb: How to deploy without Apache server

Tags: django, apache, cgi, couchdb

I'm new to CouchDB so be gentle...

I am really liking the features of CouchDB and from what I see it really complements Django well, but I don't really understand if the two are able to be deployed in a commercial environment. Here is my question:

If you decide to use Django with CouchDB, does this mean you have to deploy using the Apache server? Ideally, it would be great if CouchDB would take the job of serving pages. From what I understand, it seems that if you want to handle web logic using the Django framework, you must use a CGI compatible web server.

**EDIT:**

More clarification: Is it possible to use the Django framework and CouchDB WITHOUT another server (most commonly Apache Server or the Django development server) to handle requests? Reason being: CouchDB is already designed to handle many concurrent connections and is designed to scale well. It seems like a waste to use CouchDB and not use it to serve pages directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Django with Couchdb in production. We have Django under Apache, but using Couchdb doesn't affect what Django runs under.

In Django, you would just use a library to talk to Couchdb. Couch uses http as the protocol the library uses to talk to the db. By default, Couch listens only on localhost.

Couchapp can serve up pages, but I find the way Django does it to be more elegant. It seems to only be appropriate for mostly static pages and sites.

Comment: In your setup, does Django save all persistent data to CouchDb? Reason I ask is that it would be very easy to scale if all you had to do was replicate the CouchDB data across servers (or peers).

Comment: Currently no. Our apps are production, but not for a large number of users, only a smaller set of important users. I use mysql for auth and other things that are built in. For example, I use couchdb for the records of applicants to our school. It's worked great for those. I do know work on a nosql backend to Django is in the works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have several options and it really comes down to what objectives you wish to achieve as each solution brings additional features/controls.

One would be to use NGINX and Apache, have NGINX server static files for your django application and if possible might be able forge a bridge to have it serve file attachments from a couchdb-document (not sure if that is actually possible).  You would also have NGINX serve as a proxy to the apache/django portion to handle application logic.

The other option would be to use a 'couchapp' to actually serve content out of your couchdb.  Which I think you can also configure NGINX to be a proxy that sits in front of the couchapp should you need seo friendly urls.

Lastly, maybe consider setting up a nodejs app using express.  The nodejs application would give friendly urls and since it is all javascript it might work better with couchdb than django/python.

I'm by far no expert in the area, most of my experience is nginx/apache and django, but I've been following couchdb for quite sometime and there was a time when everyone would park it behind nginx for security purposes, but I believe those issues have been resolved... maybe?

Comment: Thanks Mgan, but I think what I'm looking for is more along the lines of implementing Django and Python into the actual view server instead of the default javascript. The CouchDB Guide describes how to accomplish this with Javascript but doesn't describe how to do it with other languages and what limitations that brings: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/design.html#server

Comment: When starting out, I'd recommend **against** a different language for the view server. Your code will be very similar in any language. It's probably not worth it.

Comment: What about Design Documents? This seems like a great place to use Django templates to generate HTML.

Comment: See the bottom of the figure listed here for an example of Javascript being used to generate HTML templates: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/design.html#figure/1

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling with this question. It seems a waste if the built-in web server of CouchDb; the one that serves up Futon, cannot be used for sophisticated apps.

What I have found out is the following:

It is possible to place rewrite rules in CouchDb, as explained here: http://blog.couchbase.com/rewrites-and-virtual-hosting-introduction and one can map simple pages into elegant web urls. But it looks strongly to me that such a server would only serve pages within the framework of the document based database of CouchDb (i.e. CRUD applications that handles data in the CouchDb) Such websites would be inherently scalable by using the inbuilt replication features of CouchDb

For those situations which require a CGI application, I think one would need to run another server; say on a sub-domain, using a more traditional server such as Apache, Ngnix, etc. But this could break the scalability. It would be nice if someone can show me how to invoke CGI from within a CouchDb itself. That would be really wonderful